# Reactive array for Mongo selector to populate Datatable in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, datatables, reactive-programming

(Edited to reduce scope of questions)

This is a follow-on to [Passing array via ReactiveVar in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29381734/4168250), which discussed arrays as reactive variables but did not go into detail on implementation.  Apologies for the lengthy post but I have two intertwined issues.

My objective is to allow a user to populate a datatable with information on companies, which are held in a collection.  The user enters the company name in an input box, which populates an array on click.  This array then updates a selector, which determines what subset of the collection should be displayed.

I am using the manuel:reactivearray package.  I looked at templates:array, but there was an explicit note saying it is only for client-side and I wondered if that would cause a problem.  The code below populates my DataTable with a row for Apple, which is hard coded into the array declaration.  I can also push new values to the array and see it populated in the console.  So the code is working properly.

I have two questions:

- Storage of variables

Basic Javascript question, but is this ReactiveVariable stored somewhere?  It is destroyed on a browser refresh.  Everything I have read on the topic either refers to localstorage, which would be browser-specific, or gives examples of hard coded values, which doesn't help at all.  I don’t see how a user can add additional values at a later time or view the template on a different device.

- Tracker.autorun syntax

Can someone help me with the Tracker.autorun code so that the selector is updated based on changes to the array?  The code I've added, using the examples from http://reactivearray.meteor.com/, results in an unexpected token error.

Thanks for your patience and any guidance in advance.

client/company_comps.js

```
compset = new ReactiveArray(["Apple"]);

Template.CompanyComps.events ({
    'click .addComp': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    comp = document.getElementById("comp");
    compset.push(comp.value);
    comp.value = "";
    return compset;
    }
});

Template.CompanyComps.helpers({
    Tracker.autorun(function() { //these two lines crash my app
        compset.depend();        //these two lines crash my app
        //Define selector for datatable - select documents whose "name" is in "compset" array
        comps: function () {
            return {name: {$in: compset.array()}};
        }
    })
});
```

client/company_comps.html

```
<template name="CompanyComps">
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>Comps</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form class="addComps">
                <input type="text" name="comp" id="comp" placeholder="Type company name" />
                <button type="submit" class="addComp">Add Company</button>
            </form>
            <br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{> tabular table=TabularTables.Comps selector=comps id="comps" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

lib/datatables.js

```
TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Comps = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "Comps",
    collection: Companies,
    columns: [
        {data: "name", title: "Company"},
        {data: "sector", title: "Sector"},
        {data: "capTable.marketCap", title: "Market Cap"}
    ]
});
```